# Encoding json data for a mailto link

Tags: javascript, html, json, mailto

How do I properly encode a mailto link with JSON data in the query parameters so that the link works as expected when some of the JSON data possibly includes spaces?

Here is a simple example:

```
var data = {
 "Test": "Property with spaces"
};

var mailTo = 'mailto:?body=http://www.google.com/?body=' + JSON.stringify(data);

document.getElementById("link").href = mailTo;
```

The resulting link in the email after clicking the link looks like this:

[image: link]

Here is a JSBin showing what I am talking about:

https://jsbin.com/vuweyemeji/1/edit?html,js,output

Edit: Adding encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent() doesn't seem to work for me.  I tried adding either of those methods around the data object and when I click the mailto link the url still looks the same in outlook.

Comment: use `encodeURI()` to  encode the special characters in the string before you put it into the link.

Comment: change `JSON.stringify(data)` to `encodeURI(JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: That doesn't work.  I added encodeURI() to the stringified json data and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) twice, because you are encoding a parameter inside another parameter.

Your link is using the `mailto` protocol and using a `body` parameter which content should be encoded. But, inside that content you are entering a URL which has parameters, so, this parameters should be encoded also.

Try this:

```js
var data = {"Test": "Property with spaces"};
var mailTo = 'mailto:?body=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.google.com/?body=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data)));
document.getElementById("link").href = mailTo;
```

```html
<a id='link'>anchor</a>
```