# How to receive form data as email in html

Tags: html

I am creating a portfolio, the code below is the front end of the form that uses html, the form takes 5 inputs from the user. How can I make the server side so that the data is mailed to an account via email.

```
<form class="contact-form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type = "text" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type = "text" placeholder="E-mail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type = "text" placeholder="Subject">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type = "text" placeholder="How did you hear about me?">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea placeholder = "Message" ></ textarea >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button class="site-btn">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @ you have to use some programming languages with database for backend . after that form data is mailed into account..

Comment: http://form.guide/email-form/email-form-mailto.html

Comment: You need a server with code to handle the mailing on the backend. The best you can do on the front end is: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527556/encoding-json-data-for-a-mailto-link